# Why is a div with "display: table-cell;" not affected by margin?

Tags: html, css

I have `div` elements next to each other with `display: table-cell;`.

I want to set `margin` between them, but `margin: 5px` has no effect. Why?

My code:

```
<div style="display: table-cell; margin: 5px; background-color: red;">1</div>
<div style="display: table-cell; margin: 5px; background-color: green;">1</div>
```

Answer (score 327, accepted):

### Cause

From [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/margin):

> [The margin property] applies to all elements except elements with
>   table display types other than table-caption, table and inline-table

In other words, the `margin` property is *not* applicable to `display:table-cell` elements.

### Solution

Consider using the [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-spacing) property instead.

Note it should be applied to a parent element with a `display:table` layout and `border-collapse:separate`.

For example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">123</div>
        <div class="cell">456</div>
        <div class="cell">879</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.table {display:table;border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:5px;}
.row {display:table-row;}
.cell {display:table-cell;padding:5px;border:1px solid black;}
```

### **See [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FhQwb/1/)**

---

**Different margin horizontally and vertically**

As mentioned by Diego Quirós, the `border-spacing` property also accepts two values to set a different margin for the horizontal and vertical axes.

For example

```css
.table {/*...*/border-spacing:3px 5px;} /* 3px horizontally, 5px vertically */
```

Comment: Thanks! There is also this notation in case horizontal and vertical space need to be diferent border-spacing: horizontal vertical;

Comment: And I thought I found a bug; turns out I need to learn more CSS.

Comment: I guess this doesn't really handle specific left/right/top/bottom margins though? And no way to have a specific table-cell have different padding from the rest?

Comment: @Nathan `padding` can be set for any selector necessary (e.g. class or id), as usual. If you mean the `margin` between the cells, then that can be set separately for the vertical and horizontal axes by setting two values to `border-spacing`, but it will apply to the entire table and not to individual cells.

Comment: What you posted works. But I actually would like to have border-spacing-top - but that doesn't exist. So I will need to keep looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 23):

You can use inner divs to set the margin.

```
<div style="display: table-cell;">
   <div style="margin:5px;background-color: red;">1</div>
</div>
<div style="display: table-cell; ">
  <div style="margin:5px;background-color: green;">1</div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1fb72tk3/)

Comment: This is a good idea if you want margin between the cells but not left or right of them. Then your CSS could be something like `.inner-div { margin-right: 5px; } .outer-cell:last-child .inner-div { margin-right: 0; }`. But also note this gotcha: the red and green backgrounds of this example won't necessarily match in height since they're not on the cells.

Answer (score 10):

Table cells don't respect margin, but you could use transparent borders instead:

```
div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

Note: you can't use percentages here... :(

Answer (score 2):

If you have div next each other like this

```
<div id="1" style="float:left; margin-right:5px">

</div>
<div id="2" style="float:left">

</div>
```

This should work!

Comment: Ok, but what if he want two divs in equal height? Float can't do this.

Comment: And that's why [JS](https://css-tricks.com/equal-height-blocks-in-rows/) is awesome :)

Comment: @ChrisHappy Never use JavaScript, when there is a CSS solution. Your code just gets bulky.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 As responsiveness comes on demand, the bulky CSS solutions are no longer sufficient...

Comment: They are sufficient - especially with responsive requirements. Just take a look at [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) which is now supported by [most of the major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and solves this exact problem very easily. Layouting styles should never be done by JavaScript.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 I am coming back to this in 2020 and realize how wrong I was. Sorry for my pride and thank you for your patience with me.

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking how to use `display: table-cell;` (so to make equal height) and also have `left-margin`. No proposed solutions worked for me. So I came to my dump workaround - I just added one more span with `display: table-cell;` with width of the size required margin. Not elegant but it works.