# CSS: How to create a <li> with 100% width

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I can't get my horizontal `<ul>` Tab-List working the way I want. The `<li>` with the `class ltab` should fill 100% of the available space.

```
<style>
  ul.tabs{
    width:100%;
    display: table;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  ul.tabs li{
    float:left;
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding:4px 8px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-right:4px;
    border:1px;
  }

  ul.tabs li.ltab{
    white-space:nowrap;
  }     
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li><a href='#'>Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href='#'>Tab 2</a></li>
  <li class="ltab">&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

Adding `width:100%` to the `ul.tabs li.ltab` causing this tab moving to the next line. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @TimVermaelen: No changes, still in next line.

Comment: the float is the problem, it makes it an inline element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `display:table` was a good start, the only thing left was setting `display:table-cell` on the `li`'s and forcing the first ones to the smallest width with `width:1px` while allowing the last one to fill all the remaining space with `width:100%`.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dqNLR/1/

Comment: Do you know how I can keep the `margin-right:5px` between the `<li>` ? Actually this is ignored and I have no space between the tabs anymore

Comment: Margins won't work with `display:table-cell`. You can try using `border-right: 5px solid transparent` (if you are not using borders, otherwise add your borders to an element inside the `li``). You can also use `border-spacing: 5px`. I will make you another jsfiddle with a few options you have.

Comment: Nevermind, found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398823/why-does-a-div-with-display-table-cell-not-affected-by-margin :)

Comment: awesome :) here a jsfiddle with some more possibilities: http://jsfiddle.net/dqNLR/3/