# CSS Display table cell margin not working

Tags: html, css, margin, css-tables

Display table cell margin not working..try to add margin in percentage but not working.  Here is my html code

```
<div class="mainbody clearfix">
<div class="leftpart">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="rightpart">&nbsp;</div>
<br>
<br>
.
.
.
<br>
<div class="cl"></div>
</div>
```

Here is my CSS code

```
.mainbody{
width:100%; 
display:table; 
margin:12px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.leftpart{
width:23%; 
display:table-cell;  
background-color:#ededed; 
border-right:solid 1px #a7a7a7; 
margin-right:2%; 
}

.rightpart{ 
width:75%; 
display:table-cell; 
background-color:#ccc;   
}
```

please help me

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/16398904/2388219 and has the solution you are after.

Comment: Ok, But i want border-spacing only one side in div

Comment: i want border-spacing only one side in div

Like Product listing page (leftside product link and right side product thumbs )

Answer (score 0):

Using `float:left` to the `class` would apply `margin` to the `Div`. But not sure if this solves your problem.

Comment: yes, margin apply but i have already tried
height is not working..(not 100%).