# vertically centering one and two line text buttons

Tags: html, css

I think this is a simple one but I have a row of buttons: one that is just one short word and two that are 3 long words so they run to two lines.

How can I get them to vertically center in the button? I have tried some variations of display:table-cell etc but couldn't get it exactly right.

Some code:

```
<div id="button_menu">  

<ul>
<li class='faq'><a href="#" tabindex="27">FAQs</a></li>
<li class='map'><a href="#" tabindex="28">Interactive Property Map</a></li>
<li class='request'><a href="#" tabindex="29">Request a Presentation</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MFMBR/)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#button_menu {
    font-family:"adelle", Georgia, Times, serif;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:700;
    float:right;

    position:relative;
}

#button_menu ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:40px 10px 0px 0px;
    padding:0px;
    display:table;
    border-spacing:5px;
}

#button_menu ul li{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:18px;
    height:45px;    
    padding:0px;
    vertical-align:middle;

   -moz-border-radius: 4px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
   border-radius: 4px; /* future proofing */
}
```

JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/MFMBR/1/  Important - you have to use border-spacing, instead of margin, because margin can't be applied to display:table-cell elements. More: [Why is a div with "display: table-cell;" not affected by margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398823/why-does-a-div-with-display-table-cell-not-affected-by-margin)

Comment: yes, that was my problem with using display:table-cell...there didn't seem to be a way to add margin to the left of each button. Thanks very much.