# div height depends another div height

Tags: css, html

I have two divs that one of them is dependant on the other one.

```
|Second Div| |First Div|
|          | |         |
|          | |         |
|          | |         |
```

The height of the first div defined:

```
height:auto;
```

My problem is how to define the second div height so it will be like the first.

Comment: use jQuery to get the height of another div.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal Can't I do it just with css?

Comment: there is a pure css solution , check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display:table/table-cell`:

```css
.parent{
  display:table;
  width:600px; /* some value*/
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left{
  display:table-cell;
  height: 500px; /* some value*/
  background: red;
}

.right{
  display:table-cell;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/n8Lqrqvv/)

Comment: When I omit the height property from the right div, it isn't shown at all.
Actually, the right div doesn't have any value inside it but a border, which is not shown when I omit the height.

Comment: Did you put a `display:table` parent?

Comment: When I put that property on the parent div, it ignores the width property of the children.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n8Lqrqvv/2/

When you uncomment the height, the lines are begin shown.

Comment: You have to add some `width` to the `.parent`. Also, you don't need `float` because they are rendered like `table-cells` - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/n8Lqrqvv/3/)

Comment: Ok, now it's almost fully working.
There is an issue with 'margin-right' which is ignored.
I assume that that is because we are acting like a table cell.
I have tried to use 'cell-spacing' which also didn't work.

Comment: Yes, `margin` doesn't work with `table-cell` - [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16398904/1763929). You can add a third `table-cell` that will simulate that `margin-right` - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/n8Lqrqvv/4/)

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="div1">first div</div>   
<div class="div2"></div>
```

css:

```
 div{display: table-cell;width: 100px;vertical-align: top}  /*display: table-cell;*/
.div1{height:auto; background:red;}
.div2{background:green;}
```

**working jsFiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/L54xz1h9/4/

Comment: I think your answer is correct! I have a small doubt  why is it not showing any result if we first div from ur code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use java script to do so.

```
<div id="firstDiv">
   <!--Your contents--> 
</div>
<div id="secondDiv"> 
   <!--Your contents--> 
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">        
    document.getElementById("secondDiv").style.height = (document.getElementById("firstDiv").clientHeight - 10) + "px";
</script>
```

It is tested.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is flexbox, and your elements will be the same height:

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.flex-container {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
}

.flex-item {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    width: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px
}
```

jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/242wro9e/

Answer (score 0):

Set property display:table-cell; for both div then height of your div adjust automatically so the second div height so it will be like the first.

Answer (score 0):

As  Bhojendra - C-Link Nepal  has already mentioned use jquery to get the height of first div!

Here is some tutorial for you:-

[click here](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Check the examples at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your layout will allow, but a simple solution is to put first div inside second div.

```
|Second Div |First Div||
|           |         ||
|           |         ||
|           |         ||
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69wfzkmo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.offsetHeight` to get the height, if the element's `height` is set to `auto`. It returns the `height` including the `padding` and `border`, so if it exists you can remove it using `try / catch` statements.

```js
var first = document.getElementById('first');
var second = document.getElementById('second');
var h = first.offsetHeight;

try {
  h -= parseInt(getComputedStyle(first).paddingTop.slice(0, -2), 10);
  h -= parseInt(getComputedStyle(first).paddingBottom.slice(0, -2), 10);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}

try {
  h -= parseInt(getComputedStyle(first).borderTopWidth.slice(0, -2), 10);
  h -= parseInt(getComputedStyle(first).borderBottomWidth.slice(0, -2), 10);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
second.style.height = h + 'px';
```

```css
#first {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  background-color: chocolate;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
#second {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: sienna;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</div>
<div id="second">Text</div>
```