# float:right CSS property changes the vertically center position of the button inside div

Tags: css

The `<button>` element in the following code is vertically centered, when it is not **right aligned** using the CSS `float:right` property.

### HTML

---

```
<div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">bob</b>
    <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
</div>
<div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">harri</b>
    <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
</div>
<div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">harri2</b>
    <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
</div>
<div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">kaleeem</b>
    <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
</div>
<div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">nehaaa</b>
    <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
</div>
<div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">nitiisha</b>
    <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
</div>
<div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">rangi</b>
    <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
</div>
<div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">tom</b>
    <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
</div>
```

### CSS

---

```
.opponents_list {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 3em;
    margin: 0.1em auto;
    background: #333;
}
.opponent_list_bold_name {
    line-height: 3em;
}
.opponent_list_button {
    float: right;
}
```

The fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3LL94rc6/1/). 
How can I make the button both right aligned and vertical center?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me the best solution is to use `display: table` technique(as i answer in your previous question):

```css
#playerlist {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.opponents_list {
  height: 3em;
  margin: 0.1em auto;
  background: #666;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-row;
}
.opponent_list_bold_name {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 100%;
}
.tableCell {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">bob</b>

  <div class="tableCell">
    <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">harri</b>

  <div class="tableCell">
    <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">harri2</b>

  <div class="tableCell">
    <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">kaleeem</b>

  <div class="tableCell">
    <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="opponents_list"><b class="opponent_list_bold_name">nehaaa</b>

  <div class="tableCell">
    <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The margin is not displayed. Even setting it to higher value has no effect

Comment: [The margin property] applies to all elements except elements with table display types other than table-caption, table and inline-table from [MDN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398823/why-is-a-div-with-display-table-cell-not-affected-by-margin).Consider using the border-spacing property instead.
Note it should be applied to a parent element with a display:table layout and border-collapse:separate.

Comment: Thank you very much. What kind of approach you would have taken to display the online player names as list and to invite them(a right aligned button) considering the webpage is to be displayed on mobile device ?. Just want to make sure i am not doing anything stupid as html is new to me.

Comment: With that approach you won't have any problem. You can also check it on chrome mobile view.

Comment: In the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m74nkkym/ there is a space b/w the invite button and the name. That is not desired.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66593/discussion-between-alex-char-and-talespin-kit).

Answer (score 1):

Put your button into a div, add `line-height` and `float: right` to that div. Here is a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3LL94rc6/3/)**

```
<div class="opponents_list">
    <b class="opponent_list_bold_name">bob</b>
    <div style="line-height: 3em; float: right;">
        <button class="opponent_list_button" type="button">Invite</button>
    </div>
</div>
```