# how to get spacing between divisons

Tags: html, css

```css
body{background-image: url(images/boy_naruto_blond_drop_stern_look_24237_1366x768.jpg);background-attachment: fixed; }
@font-face{
font-family:pagal;
    src:url("fonts/Pagal Font.ttf");}
    @font-face{
font-family:folktale;
src:url("fonts/Folktale.ttf");
}
#titl{
    font-family:folktale;
    text-align:center;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-stretch: ultra-expanded;
font-size: 40px;
    background: rgba(44,95,188,0.3);
    back


}
h1{color: rgb(255,201,14);margin-bottom: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;border: 0px;}
sub{margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 0px;border-spacing: 0px;}
.icon{height: 150px;width: 200px;text-align: center;}
#naruto{display: table-cell;padding: 20px;background: rgba(220,199,48,0.5);}
#sasuke{display: table-cell;padding: 20px;background: rgba(81,81,255,0.5);}
#sakura{display: table-cell;padding: 20px;background: rgba(231,126,176,0.5);}
#container{display: table-row;}
#table1{display: table;margin: 50px;text-align: center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="titl"><h1>NARUTO</h1><sub>never give up</sub></div>
    <div id="table1"><div id="container">
    <div id="naruto"><table><tr><td><img src="images/the_smile_of_uzumaki_by_katsuuyu-d6g8nw6.png" alt="naruto" class="icon"></td></tr><tr><td>NARUTO UZUMAKI</td></tr></table></div>
    <div id="sasuke"><table><tr><td><img src="images/sasuke__s_smile_by_gaarajapanime-d4n09eb.png" class="icon" alt="sasuke"></td></tr><tr><td>SASUKE UCHIHA</td></tr></table></div>
    <div id="sakura"><table><tr><td><img src="images/Sakura.PNG" class="icon" alt="sakura"></td></tr><tr><td>SAKURA HARUNA</td></tr></table></div></div></div>



</body>






</html>
```

i am trying to get space between the naruto sasuke and sakura blocks. I represented each div(naruto,sasuke,sakura) as table cells and enclosed these three divs in another div(display:table row) and finally in div(id=table1,display:table). please help me.

imageLink:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9RbEZnGFP1JUjE3N1NjZGJoUFU/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the issue you want a space between each block? If that so, assign a class (ie `.cell`) to naruto, sasuke and sakura. Then use

```
.cell { 
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

This will add a margin of 0 at the top and the bottom and a spacing of 5px on each side.

Also avoid repeating in CSS. You could merge `display: table-cell;padding: 20px;` and put this in your `.cell` class. It will be easier if you need to change the padding, for exemple ;)

Hope this helped.

Comment: i tried what you said even though the problem not solved. What to do?

Answer (score 1):

Insert the following into `#table1`

```
border-spacing:5px; border-collapse:separate;
```

For more info see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16398904/4665

```css
body{background-image: url(images/boy_naruto_blond_drop_stern_look_24237_1366x768.jpg);background-attachment: fixed; }
@font-face{
font-family:pagal;
    src:url("fonts/Pagal Font.ttf");}
    @font-face{
font-family:folktale;
src:url("fonts/Folktale.ttf");
}
#titl{
    font-family:folktale;
    text-align:center;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-stretch: ultra-expanded;
font-size: 40px;
    background: rgba(44,95,188,0.3);
    back


}
h1{color: rgb(255,201,14);margin-bottom: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;border: 0px;}
sub{margin-top: 0px;padding-top: 0px;border-spacing: 0px;}
.icon{height: 150px;width: 200px;text-align: center;}
#naruto{display: table-cell;padding: 20px;background: rgba(220,199,48,0.5);}
#sasuke{display: table-cell;padding: 20px;background: rgba(81,81,255,0.5);}
#sakura{display: table-cell;padding: 20px;background: rgba(231,126,176,0.5);}
#container{display: table-row;}

#table1{display: table;margin: 50px;text-align: center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto; border-spacing:5px; border-collapse:separate;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div id="titl"><h1>NARUTO</h1><sub>never give up</sub></div>
    <div id="table1"><div id="container">
    <div id="naruto"><table><tr><td><img src="images/the_smile_of_uzumaki_by_katsuuyu-d6g8nw6.png" alt="naruto" class="icon"></td></tr><tr><td>NARUTO UZUMAKI</td></tr></table></div>
    <div id="sasuke"><table><tr><td><img src="images/sasuke__s_smile_by_gaarajapanime-d4n09eb.png" class="icon" alt="sasuke"></td></tr><tr><td>SASUKE UCHIHA</td></tr></table></div>
    <div id="sakura"><table><tr><td><img src="images/Sakura.PNG" class="icon" alt="sakura"></td></tr><tr><td>SAKURA HARUNA</td></tr></table></div></div></div>



</body>






</html>
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your solution worked exactly as i wanted. i was striving to achieve it for 1 day.

Answer (score 1):

I took another approach and change display:table-cell; by display:inline-block;

try this code:

```
#naruto{display:inline-block; margin-right:10px;padding: 20px;
background: rgba(220,199,48,0.5);}
#sasuke{display:inline-block; margin-right:10px;padding: 20px;
background: rgba(81,81,255,0.5);}
#sakura{display:inline-block; margin-right:10px;padding: 20px;
background: rgba(231,126,176,0.5);}
```