# Why "text-align: left;" does not work here?

Tags: css

I have used `text-align: left;` in the css class `name-tag` but somehow the name is still aligned to the right hand side of the div. Why?

```css
.container {
    width:500px;
    position:absolute;
    display:table;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

.img-circle {
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    border: 2px solid  #666;
    font: 32px Arial, sans-serif;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.name-tag {
    display:table-cell;
    padding-left:75px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div style="container">
    <div class='img-circle'>
        AK
    </div>
    <div class='name-tag'>
        Aaron King
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/kongakong/6Lrfwt7m/3/

The outcome is this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your fiddle you have `<div style="container">` instead of `<div class="container">`

Then you have padding of `75px` so its not totally on the left.

Comment: I was wondering why `container` class did not work. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @AnthonyKong No problem...small mistakes are the worst!

Comment: A quick follow-up: I switch to use margin-left but name-tag is touching the circle. How can I keep a small gap between these two elements?

Comment: @AnthonyKong That is because in table-cell the margin won't work. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398823/why-is-a-div-with-display-table-cell-not-affected-by-margin

Answer (score 2):

It is aligned to the left, you just have large padding to make it seem like it's not. Remove `padding-left:75px;` and your problem is fixed.

Comment: A quick follow-up: I switch to use `margin-left` but `name-tag` is touching the circle. How can I keep a small gap between these two elements?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that there is padding on left and so the cell seems aligned at right.

if you remove the padding you can see that is working correctly.
Check this fiddle:

```
.name-tag {
display:table-cell;
padding-left:75px;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align:left;
border: 1px solid black;
padding-left:0;
padding-right:30px;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/6Lrfwt7m/8/

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS Box Sizing for width fixed in padding.

```
.name-tag {

        display:table-cell;
        padding:10px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: left;
        border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing:border-box;

}
```