# negative margin-top and scroll up

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I need to set `margin-top` < `100` or `200px` and be able to scroll up till the `first` and `last eight` element.

If I set `margin-top: -200px;` I will not be able to scroll up until the top.

```css
ul {
  margin-top: -50px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin-top: -200px;
}

.container {
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
    <li>fifth</li>
    <li>sixth</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>eight</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `display:table-cell` for the `ul` elements. That will overcome the negative margin issue.

```css
ul {
  display:table-cell;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  margin-top: -200px;
}

.container {
  height: 50px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>first</li>
    <li>second</li>
    <li>third</li>
    <li>fourth</li>
    <li>fifth</li>
    <li>sixth</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>eight</li>
    <li>eight</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I use either `margin-top` or jquery `.animate()` to scroll down to a predefined `li`? thanks a lot

Comment: Check this question for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398823/why-is-a-div-with-display-table-cell-not-affected-by-margin

Comment: actually this works with `.animate()` so this issue is solved. my project must have something that is blocking `.animate()` to scroll down .. thanks for the help .. I decided to accept your answer