# How to make a list with each row divided into two columns, with the first column growing to the size of its contents?

Tags: css, width, column-width

Originally I needed this for a chat app. Now I need it for something else as well... I figure I'd better ask.

Elaborating the chat app example: chat messages are `li`s, they have two `span`s: one for the author's nick, the other one for the message, I'd like the size of all spans to be equal (for aesthetic purposes) and grow to fit the longest nick.

## Failed attempts:

**1. Flexbox**

```css
span {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.author {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.author:after {
  content: ":";
}

.message {
  flex: auto;
}

li {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="author">nick</span><span class="message">Don't you Remember, the Fifth of November, 'twas Gunpowder Treason Day, I let off my gun, and made'em all run. And Stole all their Bonfire away.</span></li>
  <li><span class="author">SomeOtherLongerNick</span><span class="message">Miss Susie had a steamboat, the steamboat had a bell. The steamboat went to Heaven, Miss Susie went to ...</span></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see the width of the nick field is not equal among messages which, IMO, is ugly.

**2. Fixed width**

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.author {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.author:after {
  content: ":";
}

.message {
  width: 65%;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="author">nick</span><span class="message">Don't you Remember, the Fifth of November, 'twas Gunpowder Treason Day, I let off my gun, and made'em all run. And Stole all their Bonfire away.</span></li>
  <li><span class="author">nick2</span><span class="message">Miss Susie had a steamboat, the steamboat had a bell. The steamboat went to Heaven, Miss Susie went to ...</span></li>
</ul>
```

As you can see the width doesn't adapt to the lengths of the nicks with the result being a large waste of space.

**3. Grid**

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
}

.author {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}

.author:after {
  content: ":";
}

span {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="author">nick</span><span class="message">Don't you Remember, the Fifth of November, 'twas Gunpowder Treason Day, I let off my gun, and made'em all run. And Stole all their Bonfire away.</span>
  <span class="author">OtherNick</span><span class="message">Miss Susie had a steamboat, the steamboat had a bell. The steamboat went to Heaven, Miss Susie went to ...</span>
</div>
```

This seems to work (gives the desired result) but nonetheless I list this among failed attempts for two reasons:

1. This requires me to get rid of `li`s and bring all `span`s to the outer level. This, IIUC, breaks the semanticity of HTML markup, since semantically all those `span`s are not on the same level and hence should be grouped.
2. This makes things more cumbersome if I want to, for example, provide borders, shading, etc, to chat entries. Instead of applying styles to a single `li`, I have to apply them to two `span`s and be careful to make them overlap correctly.

What is the correct way to achieve what I want to achieve?

Comment: I suppose the preference is to do this all with CSS and avoid javascript? JS might be the required trade-off to not using CSS Grid for the reasons you specified.

Comment: A list with columns? Sounds like a table to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost good with your grid solution. You can keep the `li` element by introducing `display:contents` (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents) but you will still not be able to style the `li` since this one will no more generate a box content:

```css
ul {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
}
li {
  display:contents;
}

.author {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}

.author:after {
  content: ":";
}

span {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="author">nick</span><span class="message">Don't you Remember, the Fifth of November, 'twas Gunpowder Treason Day, I let off my gun, and made'em all run. And Stole all their Bonfire away.</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="author">OtherNick</span><span class="message">Miss Susie had a steamboat, the steamboat had a bell. The steamboat went to Heaven, Miss Susie went to ...</span></li>
</ul>
```

Another way is to consider `display:table` like below:

```css
ul {
  display: table;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
}

.author {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}

.author:after {
  content: ":";
}

span {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="author">nick</span><span class="message">Don't you Remember, the Fifth of November, 'twas Gunpowder Treason Day, I let off my gun, and made'em all run. And Stole all their Bonfire away.</span>
  </li>
  <li><span class="author">OtherNick</span><span class="message">Miss Susie had a steamboat, the steamboat had a bell. The steamboat went to Heaven, Miss Susie went to ...</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! Though, it's worthy to mention, your second table example requires border-spacing for the rows to be separated, as margin is ignored : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398823/why-is-a-div-with-display-table-cell-not-affected-by-margin

Comment: @gaazkam that's why I used padding in the second example ;)

Comment: Yeah but I mean this last `span { margin-top: 10px; }`