# Reduce the bottom border width

Tags: css, sass, border, padding

I have two tabs and they have bottom-borders. This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4dGz/) example.

```
<div class="component-content">
    <div class="tabs-inner">
        <ul class="tabs-heading">
            <li tabindex="0" class="active">
                <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="component content col-12">
                            <div class="component-content">
                                <div class="field-heading">TAB 1: STANDARD SMALL</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li tabindex="-1">
                <div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="component content col-12">
                            <div class="component-content">
                                <div class="field-heading">TAB 2: STANDARD SMALL</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

.tabs-heading {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;   
    width:100%;
}
.tabs-heading li {
    display: table-cell;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

I want to add padding in the border bottom so that it should look like this

I tried to add padding-bottom but it didn't work.

Any suggestion or help would be appreciated

[image: tabs botom]

Comment: where did you add `padding-bottom`?

Comment: I tried that and also the margin-bottom but didn't work

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398823/why-is-a-div-with-display-table-cell-not-affected-by-margin/41884720

Comment: Hi @OwaisAhmed, I can see, you have added ```height:100px``` to wrapper div on ```line 9``` in ```JSFiddle example```. Even if you reduce the padding it won't help. Either you have to reduce your height, or mange the height by giving ```padding```. Hope this works for you.
Or if possible, please give some more insights, so that we would be able to have a deeper look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if I got your question right ... but maybe you are looking for something like this ...?

If you don't use `table` and `table-cell` ... but `flexbox` instead ... all tabs will get automatically the same height and you are able to work with `padding-bottom`. If you like you can add `margins` between tabs as well.

```css
#wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    background-color: Gray;
}

#wrapper div {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
}

#one {
    background-color: green
}

#two {
    background-color: blue
}

#three {
    background-color: red
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="one">one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one one</div>
    <div id="two">two two two two two two</div>
    <div id="three">three</div>
</div>
```